# Set TextView Text to the same color as the EditText fields Text Color

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview

Essentially I have it set up where the EditText field gets populated onClick (of a cell in ListView) to a certain word. I set that words color to green and it is green when present in the EditText field. Only issue is when I send that text to ListView, the text I set green in EditText is no longer green, it is the same color as the rest of the text. Anyone know of a solution for this?

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                                    long id) {

                int skull = R.drawable.image05;
                Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(skull);
                if(images[imageId] == skull){
                    Toast.makeText(ChatRoom2.this, "Skull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    String next = "<font color='#13b602'>@Skull</font>";
                    editText.setText(Html.fromHtml(next));

                    editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(ChatRoom2.this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
```

The code above populates the EditText Field

```
  addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                // String message2;

                message = editText.getText().toString();
                RowItems item = new RowItems(images[imageId], message);

                if (message.isEmpty()){

                    Toast.makeText(ChatRoom2.this, "Say Something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                else {


                    adapter.add(item);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                editText.setText("");

                //minimize keyboard bitch
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.
                        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

            }
        });
```

The code above is when the message is sent to ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `editText.getText()` (instead of `editText.getText().toString()`), and also change the type of message to `CharSequence`, then it should keep whatever markup you applied.

By converting it into a string, you are losing this information.

Comment: I tried changing my Custom adapter to charsequence but it still wont allow me to place this into -- RowItems item = new RowItems(images[imageId], message); - since it is looking for a string.

Comment: @ZombiePartie Yes, you should change all the intermediate places too. You didn't post the definition of `RowItem` so I can't tell exactly, but you should basically change both the field and the constructor parameter from String into CharSequence.

Comment: ahhh ok cool that works. Sometimes it leaves lines under the text but I think that shouldnt be too hard to fix. One question though, is there anyway to apply .isEmpty to a Charsequence? You are an Android genius by the way.

Comment: @ZombiePartie Try `.length() == 0`.